# simple question about group by and custom groups

Tags: mysql

Imagine a MySQL table that only has 2 columns: an id and a name of a color.

With this query, I know how many id's I have for each color:

```
SELECT color_name, count(id) FROM color_table GROUP BY (color_name)

red:    10 
blue:   5 
yellow: 3
green:  1
```

My question is, is there a way I can specify to the "group by" some custom groups?? I mean, is there a query that results in this:

```
red: 10
colors different than red: 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about MYSQL but you can use a CASE in the Group BY with SQL Server.

```
SELECT  CASE color_name
      WHEN 'red' THEN 'red'
      ELSE 'colors different than red'
    END AS color_group
   ,Count(id)
FROM    color_table
GROUP BY CASE color_name
      WHEN 'red' THEN 'red'
      ELSE 'colors different than red'
    END
```

Answer (score 4):

Directly using `GROUP BY`, no. You can still get the results you want, though, and there are many ways to accomplish it. Such as `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'red', COUNT(*) FROM color_table WHERE color_name='red'
UNION
SELECT 'colors different than red', COUNT(*) FROM color_table WHERE color_name <> 'red'
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it looks a little sloppy, GROUP BY is possible

```
SELECT is_it_mycolor,COUNT(1) mycolor_count FROM
(SELECT IF(color_name='red','red','colors different than red') is_it_mycolor
FROM color_table) A GROUP BY is_it_mycolor order by mycolor_count desc;
```

Here is the sample data

```
drop database if exists alex;
create database alex;
use alex
create table color_table
(id int not null auto_increment,
color_name varchar(20),primary key (id));
insert into color_table (color_name) values
('yellow'),('blue'),('red'),('red'),('red'),
('blue'),('red'),('green'),('red'),('red'),
('yellow'),('blue'),('red'),('red'),('yellow'),
('blue'),('red'),('red'),('blue');
SELECT color_name, count(id) FROM color_table GROUP BY (color_name);
```

Here is the sample data loaded

```
mysql> drop database if exists alex;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create database alex;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use alex
Database changed
mysql> create table color_table
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> color_name varchar(20),primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into color_table (color_name) values
    -> ('yellow'),('blue'),('red'),('red'),('red'),
    -> ('blue'),('red'),('green'),('red'),('red'),
    -> ('yellow'),('blue'),('red'),('red'),('yellow'),
    -> ('blue'),('red'),('red'),('blue');
Query OK, 19 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 19  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT color_name, count(id) FROM color_table GROUP BY (color_name);
+------------+-----------+
| color_name | count(id) |
+------------+-----------+
| blue       |         5 |
| green      |         1 |
| red        |        10 |
| yellow     |         3 |
+------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is my query executed against the sample data

```
mysql> SELECT is_it_mycolor,COUNT(1) mycolor_count FROM
    -> (SELECT IF(color_name='red','red','colors different than red') is_it_mycolor
    -> FROM color_table) A GROUP BY is_it_mycolor order by mycolor_count desc;
+---------------------------+---------------+
| is_it_mycolor             | mycolor_count |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| red                       |            10 |
| colors different than red |             9 |
+---------------------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 3):

For flexibility, you can use a `color_group` table, either permanent or temporary or on the fly:

```
SELECT color_group.custom_group
     , COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
FROM 
        ( SELECT 'red' AS color_name, 'red' AS custom_group UNION ALL
          SELECT 'green', 'other' UNION ALL
          SELECT 'blue' , 'other' UNION ALL
          ...
          SELECT 'black', 'other'
        ) AS color_group
    JOIN
        color_table AS c
      ON c.color_name = color_group.color_name
GROUP BY color_group.custom_group ;
```